# Dropbox file meta data from shared link

Tags: android, dropbox, dropbox-api

I've been using the Dropbox Android SDK for some years now. Currently I'm developing an application that receives a shared link from Dropbox's native Android application.

Is there any way for me to get that file's (or folder) metadata (e.g., path, size) from the shared link alone? Currently I'm querying all my files and folders for items with the name I obtain from the shared link, but that is not efficient nor will it work for items with identical names.

Is there any other (smart) way of doing this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, there's currently no API for accessing file/folder metadata via Dropbox shared links. We're tracking this as a feature request though.